# Disable body hue animation on images CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a hue animation set on my entire site body where every colorful or seethrough element has the animation like buttons images etc. I want to remove the animation on certain images though since they should have a static image. What code should I add to the image to make that happen.

```
main {
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("../img/wallpaper.jpg") center/cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: hue 10s infinite alternate;
}

main::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    filter: blur(2rem);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

@keyframes hue {
    from {
        filter: hue-rotate(0);
    }
    to {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

I tried a few different code snippets and ideas from stack overflow and other sources but none of them seemed to have work.

The main body HTML starts like this

```
<body class="Wibes">

<div class="loader">
    <div class="loader__figure"></div>
</div>

<main>

    <!-- Nav and Logo
        ================================================== -->

    <a href="index.html">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#ticket-wrap" class="ticket-link">
        <div class="ticket">
            <p>Connect Wallet</p>
        </div>
    </a>
```

And the image I want to keep static is

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="speaker-image">
        <h6>chao</h6>
        <img src="img/t1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css for the image is

```
.speaker-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.speaker-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Could you share your html?

Comment: I added the talked about html and css.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer to the problem haven't found any solutions.

Comment: you can check out my solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
main {
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("../img/wallpaper.jpg") center/cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: hue 10s infinite alternate;

}

main::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    filter: blur(2rem);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

@keyframes hue {
    from {
        filter: hue-rotate(0);
    }
    to {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    } 
    
    
}

.speaker-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.speaker-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#unwanted {
    filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

```html
<body class="Wibes">

<div class="loader">
    <div class="loader__figure"></div>
</div>

<main>

    <!-- Nav and Logo
        ================================================== -->

    <a href="index.html">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/05/03/world/what-in-the-world/WITW-PROMO/WITW-PROMO-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="">
        </div>
    </a>



    <a href="#ticket-wrap" class="ticket-link">
        <div class="ticket">
            <p>Connect Wallet</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="speaker-image">
        <h6>chao</h6>
        <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/05/03/world/what-in-the-world/WITW-PROMO/WITW-PROMO-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg" id="unwanted" alt="" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

While this is definitely not an ideal solution, I added `filter: grayscale(100%);`. This makes the image completely gray which looks like the animation is disabled on it.

Notice that I changed the src of the images so they will be displayed here in stack-snippet as well.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I'm certain that the way the whole site is set up it would not work.

Comment: @phpmaniac Hey, I edited my answer, hope this new solution will be better for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for bringing another solution but since some of the pictures have a necessity to show color that would not be the best solution for me.